Cannot populate all data from one side relation database using mikroorm
So I want to get all data from the business_status here, in the entity I have created a relationship but when I join one customer table I can't get the complete business_status data. how do I fix the query? anw, don't judge me :" I'm still learning.
this is relation in my entity Customer
export class Customers extends BaseEntity {
  @OneToOne(
    () => BusinessStatus
    (businessStatus) => businessStatus.customer,
    { cascade: [Cascade.ALL] },
  )
  businessStatus?: BusinessStatus;

  // here i set for response
  toResponse(): Customer & Timestamp {
    return {
      ...
      business_status: this.businessStatus,
      ...this.getTimestamp(),
    } as Customer;
  }
}

and this is relation in my BusinessStatus entity:
  @OneToOne({
    entity: () => Customers,
    deleteRule: "cascade",
  })
  customer!: Customers;

and here i set my query in the customer-repository
    const paginationOptions = PaginationOptionValidate.parse(params);
    const paginationHelper = new PaginationHelper(paginationOptions);

    const qb = this.clientRepositoryMikro
      .createQueryBuilder("customer")
      .select(["customer.*", "businessStatus.*"])
      .leftJoin("customer.businessStatus", "businessStatus")
      .limit(paginationHelper.take)
      .offset(paginationHelper.skip);

i already try to use .populate([ { field: "businessStatus" } ]) it works but it's only return data id fk and id pk
